Why is $\phi$ not primary for 2d free boson?
This is based on the book "Conformal field theory". Consider the 2d free boson, which action given by $$S=\frac{1}{2}g\int d^2{x}\partial_\mu \phi\partial^\mu \phi.$$ It's well-known that $$\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle=-\frac{1}{4\pi g}\ln(x-y)^2+c.$$
But it has the dilatation invariance: consider the transformation:$\phi^{\prime}(x)=\phi(\lambda x)$, it keeps $S$ invariant. So we can perform "change of variables" in path integral:
$$\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle=\int[d\phi]exp(-S(\phi))\phi(x)\phi(y)=\int[d\phi^{\prime}]exp(-S(\phi^{\prime}))\phi^{\prime}(x)\phi^{\prime}(y)=\int[d\phi^{\prime}]exp(-S(\phi))\phi(\lambda x)\phi(\lambda y).$$
So if the functional measure $[d\phi]$ do not change under dilatation, $$\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle=\langle\phi(\lambda x)\phi(\lambda y)\rangle,$$ which is obviously not true. So did this comes from anomaly? And why we do not consider the anomaly in other argument, e.g. the Ward identities (2.157)?

what do you mean by "it is obviously not true"? I would say it is obviously yes true!

It's not true because of the log. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/644174/how-does-the-2d-free-boson-transform-under-global-conformal-transformations/644271

$\phi(x)$ is not an operator in the free-boson theory. Instead, the operators are, for example, $\partial_a \phi(x)$ and $\exp ( i \phi(x) )$.

@Prahar Huh? OP never said that $\phi$ is compact...

@AccidentalFourierTransform - I don't think compactness matters. In the 2D free boson theory, the free boson $\phi(x)$ is not an operator on the Hilbert space. Derivatives of $\phi$ and exponentials of $\phi$ are operators.

@AccidentalFourierTransform - Also, I should have said $\exp [ i k \phi(x) ]$. Perhaps that's why you mentioned compactness?

@Prahar $\phi$ doesnt create normalizable states, but neither it does in higher dimensions, and we hardly care about that. Non-compact $\phi$ is definitely an operator. It is a pretty nasty one, but so are almost all of the operators we care about. If a free scalar doesn't count as an operator, then basically nothing is an operator!

The free scalar in $d>2$ is a perfectly well-defined operator. It is NOT a good operator in $d=2$. The reason for this is precisely the logarithmic 2-point function. That being said, it is a good object to talk about because other good operators can be constructed from $\phi$ (such as derivatives and exponentials).

@AccidentalFourierTransform - Here's another argument. In a CFT, unitarity implies that an operator with $\Delta = 0$ must necessarily be proportional to the identity operator. The free boson in $d=2$ violates this condition.

@Prahar That is true for compact CFTs -- a non-compact boson is described by a non-compact CFT, so that argument does not work.

@AccidentalFourierTransform - This has nothing to do with compactness. The free boson operator in two dimensions is simply not a good operator, compact or not. It has a logarithmic 2-point function. Again, this is not a bad thing. We can't work directly with $\phi$, but we can (and do) work with other operators constructed out of $\phi$.

@AccidentalFourierTransform - see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/235451/8821

You can think of it this way. Is there a local operator $\phi(x)$ which satisfies the following properties?

The rescaling $x' = \lambda x$ makes the operator transform as $\phi'(x') = \phi(x)$.
This rescaling is also a symmetry of $S[\phi] := \frac{1}{2} \int d^2x \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$.
The two-point function obeys $\left < \phi(\lambda x) \phi(\lambda y) \right > = \left < \phi(x) \phi(y) \right >$.

Yes and the solution is the identity. This is the only dilation eigenstate with a scaling dimension of 0 in a unitary theory. From this, you get that the action is zero and that the two-point function is a constant.
This is not what we want if $\phi(x)$ is to be a "free field". For this, the two-point function should not obey
\begin{align}
\Box_x^2 \left < \phi(x) \phi(y) \right > = 0.
\end{align}
Rather, it should obey
\begin{align}
\Box_x^2 \left < \phi(x) \phi(y) \right > = \delta(x - y)
\end{align}
so that the field represents a "propagating" degree of freedom. I.e. for this to really be a free field, its path integral with sources should evaluate to something with the inverse of the Laplacian. The moment you demand this, you get the logarithmic propagator that we're familiar with and hence $\phi'(x')$ is no longer $\phi(x)$. The transformation law that replaces this will bring in $\phi^2(x)$ and not leave the action invariant so you can think of that as an anomaly.
